# Why does using boost::multiprecision::cpp_int affect tail call optimization here

Tags: c++, optimization, boost

I have some templated code that compilers can tail call optimize for most data types but not others. The code implements pow()

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void powRecurse(T& x, U& y, T& acc)
{
   if(y == 0) {
      acc = Identity<T>;
      return;
   }
   if(y == 1) {
      acc = acc * x;
      return;
   }
   if(y % 2 == 1) {
      acc = acc * x;
      y = y - 1;
   }
   x = x*x; 
   y = y/2;
   powRecurse<T, U>(x, y, acc);
}

template<typename T, typename U>
T tailPow(T x, U y)
{
   T rv = Identity<T>;
   powRecurse<T, U>(x, y, rv);
   return rv;
}
```

The type of parameter T seems to have no affect on tail call optimization, any types I've tried can be tail called optimized with the right types for the parameter U. If parameter U is a uint64_t the compiler can tail call optimize. If it's boost::multiprecision::cpp_int then the compiler doesn't tail call optimize.

I've also tried wrapping a uint64_t in a class and a template wrapper on an int type which both tail call optimize.

Is there any reason this shouldn't tail call optimize? Obviously I could loop this but I'm really just trying to understand the language or compiler issues here.

Comment: Obvious, but probably useless comment: compiler has no obligations in optimizations and they are, afaik, a bunch of heuristics, so if `cpp_int` is "big enough" then compiler may think that tail recursion does not worth it. It's quite interesting why, but I doubt it can be answered without good knowledge in gcc's (or other compiler's) internals.

Comment: @yeputons thanks, mostly I'm not sure that there isn't something in cpp_int that makes it impossible. On the other hand I can't imagine a case where tail call optimization would be worse, though I can imagine it being an issue with length of the function after inlining and an inability of the analyzer to identify the possibility of optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy evaluation implies that all the "recursive" function calls are actually different function template instantiations.

See e.g. a similar discussion here:

- [Boost multiprecision : Recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum length 256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694512/boost-multiprecision-recursive-template-instantiation-exceeded-maximum-length/33695963#33695963)
- or here [How to use sqrt and ceil with Boost::multiprecision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457795/how-to-use-sqrt-and-ceil-with-boostmultiprecision/29459612#29459612)

So, you can have all the tail-coll implementation details as you expect it by opting out of the lazy-evaluation template expressions (`boost::multiprecision::et_off` as described in the links), but be sure to check that the reduced code-size and perceived TCO optimization **actually** leads to increased performance.

In reality, certain algorithms benefit from expression templates that can skip common sub expressions, reorder lossless operations etc.

Comment: I see! I think this may have also been why originally I had to specify template parameters to for function calls to avoid mismatched types with some of the arguments I passed.

Comment: Yes. Alternatively you can explicitly cast the arguments before passing. It's a common surprise with users using Boost Multiprecision. I wish they'd make it a bit more obvious in their documentation that `T a,b; auto c = a+b;` doesn't imply the type of `c` is `T` like with your grandfathers C++ types :)

Comment: It appears this did not address the issue though I'm not sure yet that it isn't a factor.