# Why does boost::lexical_cast throw an exception even though it converted the value?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a puzzling error on my hands. I am sure this code worked fine in an earlier version of boost, now (boost 1.72.0) it chucks an exception:

```
string problemStr = "1.03964e-312";
double problemChild = boost::lexical_cast<double>(problemStr);
```

Setting a breakpoint in boost's code:

```
namespace boost 
{
    template <typename Target, typename Source>
    inline Target lexical_cast(const Source &arg)
    {
        Target result = Target();

        if (!boost::conversion::detail::try_lexical_convert(arg, result)) {
            boost::conversion::detail::throw_bad_cast<Source, Target>();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

at the line `boost::conversion::detail::throw_bad_cast<Source, Target>();` reveals, that while the value is actually converted to double (result=1.0396399999979624E-312) the test `boost::conversion::detail::try_lexical_convert(arg, result)` failed! This then results in the exception:

```
  boost::wrapexcept<boost::bad_lexical_cast>: bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
```

I'm confused. It seems to do the conversion but still throws the exception? What am I overlooking? Or is this actually a bug?

Comment: I'm on macOS High Sierra (10.13.6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's confusing.

Couldn't repro it at first: https://wandbox.org/permlink/MWJ3Ys7iUhNIaBek - you can change compiler versions and boost version there

However, changing the compiler to clang did the trick: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ml8lQWESprfEplBi (even with boost 1.73)

Things get weirder: on my box, clang++-9 is *fine* even with asan/ubsan.

So I took to installing a few docker distributions.

It turns out that when using `clagn++ -stdlib=libc++` things break.

### Conclusion

It's not that complicated after a long chase down debuggers and standard library implementations. Here's the low-down:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double v;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::min_exponent10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::max_exponent10 << std::endl;
    assert(std::istringstream("1e308") >> v);
    assert(std::istringstream("1.03964e-312") >> v); // line 10
    assert(std::istringstream("1e309") >> v); // line 11
}
```

On libstdc++ prints:

```
-307
308
sotest: /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:11: int main(): Assertion `std::istringstream("1e309") >> v' failed.
```

On libc++:

```
-307
308
sotest: /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:10: int main(): Assertion `std::istringstream("1.03964e-312") >> v' failed.
```

Summarizing, libstdc++ is allowing [subnormal representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) in some cases:

> The 11 bit width of the exponent allows the representation of numbers between 10−308 and 10308, with full 15–17 decimal digits precision. By compromising precision, the subnormal representation allows even smaller values up to about 5 × 10−324.

It is likely that the library does do some checks to find whether there is acceptable loss of precision, but it could also be leaving this entirely to your own judgment.

### Suggestions

If you need that kind of range, I'd suggest using a multiprecision library (GMP, MPFR, or indeed Boost).

For full fidelity with decimal input formats, consider e.g. cpp_dec_float:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
using Decimal = boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50;

int main() {
    Decimal v("1.03964e-312");
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
1.03964e-312
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this exhaustive answer. I find the wandbox tool immensely useful, also thank you for this. I am using clang 10.0.0 indeed (something I failed to mention). 

About your proposal to use Decimal: a good idea. Unfortunately it is not really an option for me. My code is heavy on templates and should work with all sorts of numerical types. 

For now I am working around the problem by setting value like those to 0. They are themselves no doubt the result of a rounding error, I will pursue the cause and try to eliminate that problem there.

Comment: "All sorts of numerical types" They work! However, I recommend [turning off expression templates at the cost of some raw performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42093422/85371), because they do tend to break ("surprise") generic code. Indeed it does sound like accuracy is not really a goal since your input is already inexact, so it's probably good for you to using doubles. You could mix/match if you find that you get "boundary condition inputs" like these and want to be able to diagnose them better.